# Can't add the overflow attribute to the cell of a day in the ASP.NET calendar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I don't know why but, when I add some label in a specific day of the calendar, the cell height become bigger than what I've put in my css. First I've tried to concatenate the value and put it in just one label and adding it to the cell of the day but with no result. So now I'm adding a label for each row in my gridview in the cell of the day.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TeleReception._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="PanelAll" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="130%" CssClass="PanelCalendar">
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="850px" Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender">
            <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
            <DayStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="DayStyle" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="16pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" CssClass="NextPrevStyle" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#00A55E" ForeColor="White" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="20pt" ForeColor="#00A55E"  />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#00a55e" ForeColor="white" />
            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#EAEAEA" />
        </asp:Calendar>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Visible="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Document No_" HeaderText="Document No_" SortExpression="Document No_" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Location Code" HeaderText="Location Code" SortExpression="Location Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pay-to Name" HeaderText="Pay-to Name" SortExpression="Pay-to Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="No_" HeaderText="No_" SortExpression="No_" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit of Measure Code" HeaderText="Unit of Measure Code" SortExpression="Unit of Measure Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expected Receipt Date" HeaderText="Expected Receipt Date" SortExpression="Expected Receipt Date" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bc365_prodConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Visible="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Document No_" HeaderText="Document No_" SortExpression="Document No_" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Transfer-from Code" HeaderText="Transfer-from Code" SortExpression="Transfer-from Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Transfer-to Code" HeaderText="Transfer-to Code" SortExpression="Transfer-to Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Item No_" HeaderText="Item No_" SortExpression="Item No_" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SOL No2Soleno" HeaderText="SOL No2Soleno" SortExpression="SOL No2Soleno" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit of Measure Code" HeaderText="Unit of Measure Code" SortExpression="Unit of Measure Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Receipt Date" HeaderText="Receipt Date" SortExpression="Receipt Date" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bc365_prodConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

The `Dayrender` event handler in my vb code:

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(sender As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs)
    e.Cell.CssClass = "DayCellStyle"
    'To Show the Po
    Dim aLabel As Label = New Label()
    Dim ADate As Date = e.Day.Date
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim PoDate As Date = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Text
        If ADate = PoDate Then
            Dim PoNo = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
            Dim PoLocationCode As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
            Dim PoPayToName As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text
            Dim PoItemNo As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text
            Dim PoDescription As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text
            Dim PoQuantity = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text), 2)
            Dim PoUnitMeasureCode As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Text
            aLabel.Text = aLabel.Text + "<br>" + "<br>" + "-" + PoNo + " = " + PoLocationCode + " / " + PoPayToName + " ( " + PoItemNo + " / " + PoDescription + " ) " + PoQuantity.ToString + " * " + PoUnitMeasureCode
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(aLabel)
        End If
    Next
    'To Show the TR
    For j As Integer = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim TrDate As Date = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(8).Text
        If ADate = TrDate Then
            Dim TrNo = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Text
            Dim TrFromCode = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(1).Text
            Dim TrToCode = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(2).Text
            Dim TrItemNo = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(3).Text
            Dim TrItem2No = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(4).Text
            Dim TrDescription = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(5).Text
            Dim TrQuantity = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(6).Text), 2)
            Dim TrUnitOfMeasureCode = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(7).Text

            Dim bLabel As Label = New Label()
            bLabel.Text = bLabel.Text + "<br>" + "<br>" + "-" + TrNo + " = " + TrFromCode + " / " + TrToCode + " ( " + TrItemNo + " / " + TrItem2No + " (" + TrDescription + ")) " + TrQuantity.ToString + " * " + TrUnitOfMeasureCode
            bLabel.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(5)
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(bLabel)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And my CSS

```
body {
}

.PanelCalendar{
    margin: 0% -15% 0% -15%;
}
.DayStyle {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 141px;
    max-height: 141px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.aLabelStyle {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 141px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.DayCellStyle {
    height: 141px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I just want the height of the day to be at 141px and add an scrollbar if the labels in th cell exceeds the height.